# how to remove the letters under the dots in the ggplot2 legend?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using the code below I created the graphic even further below. However, I cannot remove the letters that are in the legend without removing the numbers from each dot as well. I hope there is some way. Look at the picture to better understand the problem.

```
library(FactoMineR)
library(factoextra)

# PCA
pca <- PCA(iris[1:4], graph=FALSE)

# Generating chart 
graph <- fviz_pca_ind(pca,
                      habillage = as.factor(iris$Species),
                      palette = c("#cc0000","#F4A460","#FF00FF"),
                      addEllipses = TRUE,
                      ellipse.type = 'convex') + 
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(20,20,20)) +
  theme_classic() 
graph
```

[image]

Comment: Add show.legend = F inside at the end of fiz_pca_ind call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

E.matt's comment answered the question. The solution is to add `show.legend=FALSE` inside of `fiz_pca_ind()` call

Comment: The answer works, but that option is not in the help file, so curious how you found that. I was trying and failing to use `guides`.

Comment: By the way, the labels are readable if you use `repel = TRUE` in the function.